# I Cant Seem to figure out what is causing Application not responging (Anr) in this code

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, arraylist, android-anr-dialog

I am Making a 10x10 Checkers game in java and android studio that has the international checkers rules. Everything is almost done but i began noticing an error, when playing the game everything works fine as intended but sometime when i click on a piece it gives an ANR. The Anr error doesn't occur constantly, at times it doesn't occur till the game is ended and sometimes it gives the error when few pieces are left while playing. I noticed it never gives an Anr when the game is just starting. it only happens in the mid or ending part of the game. i have been trying to resolve this for a week now but i cant please help me. I could only post part of my code because of the body content limit.

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final static int NUMBER_OF_PAWNS = 20; //both white and brown
    public final static int NUMBER_OF_TILES = 100;
    public final static int NUMBER_OF_PLAYABLE_TILES = 50;

    GridLayout board;
    View[] playableTileView = new View[NUMBER_OF_PLAYABLE_TILES];
    PlayableTile[] playableTile = new PlayableTile[NUMBER_OF_PLAYABLE_TILES];
    int[][] diagonal = new int[19][]; //sequences of tiles for queen moves
    ArrayList<Pawn> whitePawn = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Pawn> brownPawn = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> possibleMove = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean whiteMove = true;

    Pawn chosenPawn; //to set new position and check possible moves for a specific (marked) pawn
    Pawn consideredPawn; //to check mandatory moves for every pawn
    boolean mandatoryPawn = false; //is there a pawn (or more) that has to take another one(s)?

    int takeNumber = 0; //to show possible moves during multiple taking (if there are more branches from specific node)
    int drawCounter = 0;
    GameTree gameTree = null; //to check moves for cpu

    String whiteMoves = ""; //for database saving using checkers notation
    String brownMoves = ""; //each move and board state is separated by '#'
    String boardStates = "";


    public GameActivity() {};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        board = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);
        setDiagonals(); //for queen moves and pawn/queen takings
        measureBoard(); //and draw it with pawns after that
    }

    /* ============================== 1. Layout ===================== */

    public void measureBoard() {
        board.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int width = board.getWidth();
                int height = board.getHeight();
                drawBoard(width, height);  //to calculate width and height of a single tile
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawBoard(int width, int height) {
        View[] tile = new View[NUMBER_OF_TILES];
        int brownTileCounter = 0; //to set id value for game mechanics and listeners
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            tile[i] = new View(this);
            tile[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / 10, height / 10)); //10 x 10 tiles board
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && (i / 10) % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && (i / 10) % 2 != 0))  //which tiles should be white
                tile[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteTile));
            else {
                playableTileView[brownTileCounter] = tile[i]; //only brown tiles are playable
                playableTileView[brownTileCounter].setId(brownTileCounter + 1);
                playableTileView[brownTileCounter].setOnClickListener(this);
                brownTileCounter++;
            }

            board.addView(tile[i]);
        }
        createPawns();
    }

    public void createPawns() {
        for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PAWNS; i++) { //create pawns
            whitePawn.add(new Pawn( NUMBER_OF_PLAYABLE_TILES-i, true, false));
            brownPawn.add(new Pawn( i+1, false, false));
        }
        for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PLAYABLE_TILES; i++) { //create playableTiles
            if(i>=0 && i < 20) {
                playableTile[i] = new PlayableTile((i+1), -1); //-1 is brown pawn
                boardStates += "-"; //it will count as -1, but with only one character
            }
            else if(i>=30 && i <50) {
                playableTile[i] = new PlayableTile((i+1), 1); //1 is white pawn
                boardStates += "1";
            }
            else {
                playableTile[i] = new PlayableTile((i+1), 0); //0 means tile is empty
                boardStates += "0";
            }
        }
        boardStates += "#"; //end of
        drawPawns();
    }

    public void drawPawns() { //will be useful after every move
        for(int i=0; i<playableTileView.length; i++) {
            if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_pawn);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -1) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_pawn);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == 2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_queen);
            else if(playableTile[i].getIsTaken() == -2) playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_queen);
            else playableTileView[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
        }

        //checkGameState();
        //if(whitePawn.size() != 0 && brownPawn.size() != 0) checkForMoves();
        if(!checkGameState()) checkForMoves();
    }

    public void markPawn(Pawn wPawn, int position) { //done after onClick
        playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() - 1].getBackground().setAlpha(255);
        if (wPawn.getPosition() == position) {
            if(whiteMove) {
                if(!wPawn.getIsQueen())
                    playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() -1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_pawn); //in multiple takings
                else playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() -1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_queen);
            }
            else
                if(!wPawn.getIsQueen())
                    playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() -1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_pawn); //to show pawn instead of green cell (possible move)
                else playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() -1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_queen);
            playableTileView[wPawn.getPosition() - 1].getBackground().setAlpha(70);
            chosenPawn = wPawn;
            checkPossibleMoves(wPawn);
            if(possibleMove.size() == 0) Toast.makeText(this, R.string.another_pawn_to_move, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void markPossibleMove() {
        for(View tile : playableTileView) {  //mark legal moves for clicked pawn
            if (playableTile[tile.getId()-1].getIsTaken() == 0)
                tile.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brownTile)); //un-mark possible moves if just switching pawn
            for (Integer move : possibleMove)
                if (tile.getId() == move)
                    tile.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.possibleMove));
        }
    }

    /* ============================================================================ */

    /* ====================================== 5. Database ========================= */

    public boolean checkGameState() {

        if(whitePawn.size() == 0 || brownPawn.size() == 0 || drawCounter == 25) { //a game just ended
            try {
                GameDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new GameDatabaseHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.query("STATS", new String[]{"PLAYED", "WON", "DRAWN", "LOST"},
                        null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                ContentValues statsUpdate = new ContentValues();
                int gameUpdate;

                if(whitePawn.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.game_lost, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameUpdate = cursor.getInt(3) + 1;
                    statsUpdate.put("LOST", gameUpdate);
                }
                else if(brownPawn.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.game_won, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameUpdate = cursor.getInt(1) + 1;
                    statsUpdate.put("WON", gameUpdate);
                }

                else if(drawCounter == 25) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.game_drawn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gameUpdate = cursor.getInt(2) + 1;
                    statsUpdate.put("DRAWN", gameUpdate);
                }
                int gamesPlayed = cursor.getInt(0) + 1; //just finished game - need to update database
                statsUpdate.put("PLAYED", gamesPlayed);
                db.update("STATS", statsUpdate, null, null); //update games number (only one record in this table)

                long gameIndex = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "GAMES") + 1;
                ContentValues gamesUpdate = new ContentValues();
                gamesUpdate.put("NUMBER", gameIndex);
                gamesUpdate.put("NAME", "Partia #"+gameIndex);
                gamesUpdate.put("WHITE", whiteMoves);
                gamesUpdate.put("BROWN", brownMoves);
                gamesUpdate.put("BOARD", boardStates);
                db.insert("GAMES", null, gamesUpdate); //add another game for analysis

                cursor.close();
                db.close();

            } catch(SQLiteException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.database_unavailable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(this, store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    /* ======================================================================================= */

    public void checkForMoves() {
        //Can a pawn take another one? There can be more possibilities and if so - choose the longest ones (as
        // it is stated in game rules) and make sure the rest of the pawns cannot be moved.
        int longestTake = 0;
        ArrayList<Pawn> pawnColor;

        if(whiteMove) pawnColor = whitePawn;
        else pawnColor = brownPawn;

        for(Pawn pawn : pawnColor) {
            pawn.setPawnTree(new DecisionTree(pawn.getPosition()));
            consideredPawn = pawn;
            if(whiteMove) checkMandatoryMove(pawn.getPosition(), -1); //check for takes
            else checkMandatoryMove(pawn.getPosition(), 1);

            if(mandatoryPawn) {
                if(consideredPawn.getPawnTree() != null) { //there is a branch then
                    takeLongestBranch();
                    if(consideredPawn.getPawnTree().getLongestBranch() >= longestTake) {
                        longestTake = consideredPawn.getPawnTree().getLongestBranch(); //longest branch for a pawn
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        chooseFinalPawn(longestTake); //check all pawns' longest branches and take only the longest one
        if(whiteMove && gameTree != null) gameTree.getCurrentNode().setLengthOfWhiteTaking(longestTake);
        else if(!whiteMove && gameTree == null) {
            checkForBestMove();
            makeCpuMove();
        }
    }

    /* ========================== 4. Game Tree ========================== */

    public void makeCpuMove() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = rand.nextInt(gameTree.bestNodeList.size());
        GameNode chosenNode = gameTree.bestNodeList.get(r);
        resetBoardState(); //go back to current state to make a proper move
        chosenPawn = chosenNode.getPawn();

        if(!chosenNode.getIsThereTaking()) {
            mandatoryPawn = false;
            possibleMove.add(chosenNode.moveList.get(0));
            makeMove(chosenNode.moveList.get(0)); //make proper move as brown
        }
        else {
            mandatoryPawn = true;
            for(Integer move : chosenNode.moveList) {
                takeNumber = chosenNode.moveList.indexOf(move);
                possibleMove.add(move);
                makeMove(move); //make proper take(s) as brown
            }
        }

        gameTree = null; //all checked and move made - tree is not needed anymore
        endMove(); //switch colors - it's white to move now
    }

    public PlayableTile[] createBoardDeepCopy(PlayableTile[] board) {
        PlayableTile[] currentBoard = new PlayableTile[50];
        for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++) //deep copies of tiles and pawns
            currentBoard[i] = new PlayableTile(board[i]);
        return currentBoard;
    }

    public ArrayList<Pawn> createWhiteDeepCopy(ArrayList<Pawn> whiteState) {
        ArrayList<Pawn> currentWhite = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<whiteState.size(); i++)
            currentWhite.add(new Pawn(whiteState.get(i)));
        return currentWhite;
    }

    public ArrayList<Pawn> createBrownDeepCopy(ArrayList<Pawn> brownState) {
        ArrayList<Pawn> currentBrown = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<brownState.size(); i++)
            currentBrown.add(new Pawn(brownState.get(i)));
        return currentBrown;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> createMoveListDeepCopy(ArrayList<Integer> moveList) {
        ArrayList<Integer> currentMoveList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<moveList.size(); i++)
            currentMoveList.add(new Integer(moveList.get(i)));
        return currentMoveList;
    }

    public void checkForBestMove() {
        if(gameTree == null) {
            gameTree = new GameTree(createBoardDeepCopy(playableTile),
                    createWhiteDeepCopy(whitePawn), createBrownDeepCopy(brownPawn)); //current state to go back to
        }

        checkForMoves(); //what moves are possible in this state
        searchForNodes(brownPawn, gameTree); //create game nodes for each possible move
        checkGameNodes(); //find the situation after such moves
        chooseBestGameNode(); //and assess which move is best (or rather which are the worst and should not be considered
        gameTree.setAllNodesFound(true);
    }

    public void searchForNodes(ArrayList<Pawn> pawnColor, GameTree gameTree) {
        ArrayList<Integer> moveList = new ArrayList<>(); //combination of moves to get to a specific node
        for (Pawn pawn : pawnColor) {
            if (pawn.getPawnTree() != null) { //scenario when brown can take a pawn or more
                chosenPawn = pawn;
                for(ArrayList<Integer> branch : chosenPawn.getPawnTree().treeBranch) { //in many ways
                    for(int i=0; i<branch.size(); i++) { //and many pawns in each way
                        moveList.add(branch.get(i));
                    }
                    gameTree.gameNodeList.add(new GameNode(
                            pawn, createMoveListDeepCopy(moveList), true
                    ));
                    moveList.clear();
                }
            }

            else { //scenario when brown can move pawn
                chosenPawn = pawn;
                checkPossibleMoves(pawn);
                if(possibleMove.size() > 0) { //there are moves for this particular pawn
                    for(int i=1; i<=possibleMove.size(); i++) {
                        moveList.add(possibleMove.get(possibleMove.size() - i));
                        gameTree.gameNodeList.add(new GameNode(
                                pawn, createMoveListDeepCopy(moveList), false
                        ));
                        moveList.clear();
                    }
                    possibleMove.clear();
                } //possible move checked, there will be different ones for another board situation
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkGameNodes() {
        for(GameNode node : gameTree.gameNodeList) { //check created scenarios (nodes)
            gameTree.setCurrentNode(node);
            GameNode chosenNode = gameTree.getCurrentNode();

            if(!chosenNode.getIsThereTaking()) { //normal move in this node
                possibleMove.add(chosenNode.moveList.get(0));
                chosenPawn = chosenNode.getPawn();
                makeMove(chosenNode.moveList.get(0));
                possibleMove.clear();
            }
            else { //taking in this move
                for(Integer move : chosenNode.moveList) {
                    possibleMove.add(move);
                    chosenPawn = chosenNode.getPawn();
                    makeMove(move); //consider one as brown
                    possibleMove.clear();
                }
            }
            endMove(); //brown just make a move, check what white can do in response
            checkForMoves(); //check if white can take after just considered move
            if(mandatoryPawn) gameTree.getCurrentNode().setCanWhiteTakeAfter(true);
            else gameTree.getCurrentNode().setCanWhiteTakeAfter(false);
            resetBoardState();
            gameTree.pawnToRestore.clear(); //new node will be analyzed, previously taken pawns are irrelevant
        }
    }

    public void chooseBestGameNode() {
        for(GameNode node : gameTree.gameNodeList) { //do not consider nodes with a pawn loss
            if(!node.getCanWhiteTakeAfter()) gameTree.bestNodeList.add(node);
        }

        if(gameTree.bestNodeList.size() == 0) { //every brown move leads to losing pawn
            int pawnsTaken = 21; //how many;
            for(GameNode node : gameTree.gameNodeList) {
                if(node.getLengthOfWhiteTaking() <= pawnsTaken)
                    pawnsTaken = node.getLengthOfWhiteTaking();
            }
            for(GameNode node : gameTree.gameNodeList) {
                if(node.getLengthOfWhiteTaking() <= pawnsTaken)
                    gameTree.bestNodeList.add(node);
            } //consider only nodes with the least number of taken pawn by white

        }
    }
    public void resetBoardState() { //go back with brown pawns and restore white (if any have been taken)
        whiteMove = false;
        for(int i=0; i<playableTile.length; i++) { //get deep copy - current board state
            playableTile[i].setIsTaken(gameTree.getBoardState()[i].getIsTaken());
        }

        if(gameTree.whiteState.size() != whitePawn.size()) {
            for(int i=0; i<gameTree.pawnToRestore.size(); i++) {
                if(whitePawn.size()-1 < gameTree.restoringPawnIndex.get(i))
                    whitePawn.add(gameTree.pawnToRestore.get(i));
                else
                    whitePawn.add(gameTree.restoringPawnIndex.get(i), gameTree.pawnToRestore.get(i));
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<gameTree.brownState.size(); i++) {
            if(gameTree.brownState.size() == brownPawn.size()) { //no need to restore pawns then;
                if(brownPawn.get(i).getPosition() != gameTree.brownState.get(i).getPosition()) { //just replace them
                    brownPawn.get(i).setPosition(gameTree.brownState.get(i).getPosition());
                    brownPawn.get(i).setIsQueen(gameTree.brownState.get(i).getIsQueen());
                    brownPawn.get(i).setFirstDiagonal(gameTree.brownState.get(i).getFirstDiagonal());
                    brownPawn.get(i).setSecondDiagonal(gameTree.brownState.get(i).getSecondDiagonal());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* ================================================================================ */

    /* ========================= 3. Pawn Tree ========================================== */

    public void checkMandatoryMove(int position, int takenPawn) { //takenPawn = -1/-2 means brown pawn/queen can be taken
        consideredPawn.getPawnTree().setTakeLength(consideredPawn.getPawnTree().getTakeLength() + 1);
        if(!consideredPawn.getIsQueen()) {
            int rowImpact = (position-1)/5%2;
            checkUpTaking(position, rowImpact, takenPawn);
            checkUpTaking(position, rowImpact, 2*takenPawn);
            checkDownTaking(position, rowImpact, takenPawn);
            checkDownTaking(position, rowImpact, 2*takenPawn);
        }
        else checkQueenTakes(position);

        if(consideredPawn.getPawnTree().nodeList.size() == 1) //no takings after checking - only root node
            consideredPawn.setPawnTree(null);
        else {
            mandatoryPawn = true;
            checkTreeNodes(0, 0, 0); //no more takes in this branch -> bind nodes
        }
    }

    public void checkUpTaking(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) { //taken pawn: -1 = brown, 1 = white
        if (position > 10) { //if you'll try to take from the last row - array out of bounds
            if (position % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 4 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 - 9].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position - 9, position-4-rowImpact); //checking possible mandatory moves before clicking pawn
            }
            if ((position - 1) % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 - 5 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 - 11].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position - 11, position-5-rowImpact);
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkDownTaking(int position, int rowImpact, int takenPawn) {
        if (position <= 40) {
            if ((position - 1) % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 + 5 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 + 9].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position + 9, position+5-rowImpact);
            }
            if (position % 5 != 0 && playableTile[position - 1 + 6 - rowImpact].getIsTaken() == takenPawn &&
                    playableTile[position - 1 + 11].getIsTaken() == 0) {
                checkTreeNodes(position, position + 11, position+6-rowImpact);
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkTreeNodes(int link, int position, int takenPawnPosition) {
        DecisionTree thisTree = consideredPawn.getPawnTree(); //for better readability; last added tree - build for considered pawn
        if(position != 0) {

            if(thisTree.getPreviousNode().takenPawnPosition.size() != 0) { //does this node have any already checked branches?
                boolean branchAlreadyChecked = true;
                    for (Integer nodeBranch : thisTree.getPreviousNode().takenPawnPosition) {
                        if (takenPawnPosition != nodeBranch)
                            branchAlreadyChecked = false; //pawn hasn't been included in any branch yet
                        else { //TO DO: don't check the same pawn when taking is longer (node level 1 and 4 may be the same pawn for queen)
                            //TO DO: don't check square taking (lvl 1 and 5 is the same pawn - taking for eternity - Stack Overflow)
                            if(consideredPawn.getIsQueen()) { //there can be more ways to take the same pawn by queen
                                if(thisTree.getCurrentNode().getLevel() == 0) {
                                    branchAlreadyChecked = false; //queen can take a pawn in many ways
                                    break;
                                }
                                else {
                                    branchAlreadyChecked = true; //same pawn to take - this is reverse take, don't consider it
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                branchAlreadyChecked = true; //normal pawn can take a pawn only in one way
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                if(!branchAlreadyChecked) {
                    thisTree.getCurrentNode().takenPawnPosition.add(takenPawnPosition);
                    thisTree.setPreviousNode(thisTree.getCurrentNode());
                    thisTree.nodeList.add(new TreeNode(position, link, thisTree.getTakeLength()));
                    thisTree.setCurrentNode(thisTree.nodeList.get(thisTree.nodeList.size() - 1)); //set new node as a current one
                }
            }

            else {
                thisTree.getCurrentNode().takenPawnPosition.add(takenPawnPosition);
                thisTree.setPreviousNode(thisTree.getCurrentNode());
                thisTree.nodeList.add(new TreeNode(position, link, thisTree.getTakeLength()));
                thisTree.setCurrentNode(thisTree.nodeList.get(thisTree.nodeList.size() - 1)); //set new node as a current one
            }

            if (thisTree.getCurrentNode().getLevel() == thisTree.getTakeLength()) {
                if (consideredPawn.getIsWhite()) checkMandatoryMove(thisTree.getCurrentNode().getPosition(), -1);
                else checkMandatoryMove(thisTree.getCurrentNode().getPosition(), 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(thisTree.getCurrentNode().takenPawnPosition.size() == 0) bindTreeNodes(thisTree, thisTree.getCurrentNode()); //no more takings in this branch
            thisTree.setTakeLength(thisTree.getTakeLength() - 1); //go back one node to check different branch
            for(TreeNode node : thisTree.nodeList) {
                if(node.getPosition() == thisTree.getCurrentNode().getLink()) {
                    thisTree.setCurrentNode(node);
                    if(consideredPawn.getIsQueen()) checkDiagonals(thisTree.getCurrentNode().getPosition());
                    break; //diagonals must be checked again because node has changed; indexes aren't important here - but arrays are
                }
            }
            for(TreeNode node : thisTree.nodeList) {
                if(node.getPosition() == thisTree.getCurrentNode().getLink()) {
                    thisTree.setPreviousNode(node);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkUpTaking(GameActivity.java:515)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:496)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkDownTaking(GameActivity.java:532)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:498)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkDownTaking(GameActivity.java:528)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:498)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkUpTaking(GameActivity.java:519)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:496)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkUpTaking(GameActivity.java:515)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:496)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkDownTaking(GameActivity.java:532)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:498)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkTreeNodes(GameActivity.java:581)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkDownTaking(GameActivity.java:528)
        at store.imastudio.nigeriadraft.gameMechanics.GameActivity.checkMandatoryMove(GameActivity.java:498)
    
    read: unexpected EOF!
```